# Free native objects in short way

Tags: .net, c++-cli

if I have multiple native type variables such:

```
EmpNameC =( wchar_t *)Marshal::StringToHGlobalUni(this->textBox38->Text).ToPointer();
PyrllC =( wchar_t *)Marshal::StringToHGlobalUni(this->textBox31->Text).ToPointer();
DtbrthC=( wchar_t *)Marshal::StringToHGlobalUni(this->textBox37->Text).ToPointer();
PlcBrthC=( wchar_t *)Marshal::StringToHGlobalUni(this->textBox36->Text).ToPointer();
CIDC    =( wchar_t *)Marshal::StringToHGlobalUni(this->textBox35->Text).ToPointer();
ContNoC=( wchar_t *)Marshal::StringToHGlobalUni(this->textBox34->Text).ToPointer();
JndtC   =( wchar_t *)Marshal::StringToHGlobalUni(this->textBox33->Text).ToPointer();
PostnC  =( wchar_t *)Marshal::StringToHGlobalUni(this->textBox32->Text).ToPointer();
DeptC   =( wchar_t *)Marshal::StringToHGlobalUni(this->comboBox4->Text).ToPointer();
AnnLvC  =( wchar_t *)Marshal::StringToHGlobalUni(this->textBox9->Text).ToPointer();
EmrgLvC=( wchar_t *)Marshal::StringToHGlobalUni(this->textBox30->Text).ToPointer();
IrrC=( wchar_t *)Marshal::StringToHGlobalUni(this->comboBox1->SelectedItem->ToString()).ToPointer();
HmTwnC  =( wchar_t *)Marshal::StringToHGlobalUni(this->textBox25->Text).ToPointer();
```

I must free all of them like:

```
Marshal::FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)EmpNameC);      
Marshal::FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)DtbrthC);
Marshal::FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)PlcBrthC);
Marshal::FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)CIDC);
Marshal::FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)ContNoC);
Marshal::FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)JndtC);
Marshal::FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)PostnC);
Marshal::FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)DeptC);
Marshal::FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)AnnLvC);
Marshal::FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)EmrgLvC);
Marshal::FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)IrrC);
Marshal::FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)HmTwnC);
```

Is there any shorter way I can use to free all native objects instead of doing that once per one object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could manage it with a dedicated structure that holds a queue.

Each time you allocate a native object you push it into the queue, and at the end you free them all in a loop.